# adjective - role

Tags: adjectives

- *The boy felt guilty because he knew what he had done.*

in this sentence the word *guilty* being an adjective is modifying the verb *felt*.
Please update if my understanding is correct

Comment: You are partly right. "Feel" is one of a few verbs that can take PCs (predicative complements) with the form of an adjective phrase. "Guilty" is the PC of "felt", not a modifier.

Comment: 'Guilty' certainly refers to the referent (whoever the boy is, Jim say, specifically how he felt), but 'modify' has a technical, grammatical meaning that does not apply here.

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of whether the modification takes place with the verb or not, it is still an adjective. What you just stated is correct.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with all that you say. Yes, "guilty" is an adjective, but it's a complement of the verb "felt", not a modifier.